# What should I use to replace gettimeofday() on Windows?

Tags: windows, select, winapi, gettimeofday

I'm writing a portable Socket class that supports timeouts for both sending and receiving... To implement these timeouts I'm using `select()`.... But, I sometimes need to know how long I was blocked inside `select()` which of course on Linux I would implement by calling `gettimeofday()` before and after I call `select()` and then using `timersub()` to calculate the delta...

Given that `select()` on Windows accepts `struct timeval` for it's timeout, what method should I used to replace gettimeofday() on Windows?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I ended up finding this page: [`gettimeofday()` function for Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20100111030931/http://www.cpp-programming.net/c-tidbits/gettimeofday-function-for-windows/) (now via the Wayback Machine) which has a handy, dandy implementation of `gettimeofday()` on Windows. It uses the `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` method to get an accurate clock.

**Update**: Here's an alternative active link from the 'Unix to Windows Porting Dictionary for HPC'  [`gettimeofday()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20130406033313/http://suacommunity.com/dictionary/gettimeofday-entry.php) (now via the Wayback Machine) that points to the implementation the OP referred to. Note also that there's a typo in the linked implementation:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(_MSC_EXTENSIONS)
  #define DELTA_EPOCH_IN_MICROSECS  11644473600000000Ui64 // WRONG
#else
  #define DELTA_EPOCH_IN_MICROSECS  11644473600000000ULL // WRONG
#endif
```

The values shown are missing an extra `0` at the end (they assumed microseconds, not the number of 100-nanosecond intervals). This typo was found via [this comment](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=631#c16) on a Google code project page. The correct values to use are shown below:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(_MSC_EXTENSIONS)
  #define DELTA_EPOCH_IN_MICROSECS  116444736000000000Ui64 // CORRECT
#else
  #define DELTA_EPOCH_IN_MICROSECS  116444736000000000ULL // CORRECT
#endif
```

---

**PostgreSQL's implementation of gettimeofday for Windows:**

```
/*
 * gettimeofday.c
 *    Win32 gettimeofday() replacement
 *
 * src/port/gettimeofday.c
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2003 SRA, Inc.
 * Copyright (c) 2003 SKC, Inc.
 *
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software and
 * its documentation for any purpose, without fee, and without a
 * written agreement is hereby granted, provided that the above
 * copyright notice and this paragraph and the following two
 * paragraphs appear in all copies.
 *
 * IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE TO ANY PARTY FOR DIRECT,
 * INDIRECT, SPECIAL, INCIDENTAL, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES, INCLUDING
 * LOST PROFITS, ARISING OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE AND ITS
 * DOCUMENTATION, EVEN IF THE UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA HAS BEEN ADVISED
 * OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * THE AUTHOR SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMS ANY WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  THE SOFTWARE PROVIDED HEREUNDER IS ON AN "AS
 * IS" BASIS, AND THE AUTHOR HAS NO OBLIGATIONS TO PROVIDE MAINTENANCE,
 * SUPPORT, UPDATES, ENHANCEMENTS, OR MODIFICATIONS.
 */

#include "c.h"

#include <sys/time.h>


/* FILETIME of Jan 1 1970 00:00:00. */
static const unsigned __int64 epoch = ((unsigned __int64) 116444736000000000ULL);

/*
 * timezone information is stored outside the kernel so tzp isn't used anymore.
 *
 * Note: this function is not for Win32 high precision timing purpose. See
 * elapsed_time().
 */
int
gettimeofday(struct timeval * tp, struct timezone * tzp)
{
    FILETIME    file_time;
    SYSTEMTIME  system_time;
    ULARGE_INTEGER ularge;

    GetSystemTime(&system_time);
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&system_time, &file_time);
    ularge.LowPart = file_time.dwLowDateTime;
    ularge.HighPart = file_time.dwHighDateTime;

    tp->tv_sec = (long) ((ularge.QuadPart - epoch) / 10000000L);
    tp->tv_usec = (long) (system_time.wMilliseconds * 1000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to the relevant code from PostgreSQL: http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/port/gettimeofday.c;h=75a91993b74414c0a1c13a2a09ce739cb8aa8a08;hb=HEAD

Comment: I'm sure this is a stupid question, but I can't find an answer:  where do I find c.h?

Comment: Note that this function breaks after 2038. The fix is to ensure the type of timespec.tv_sec is NOT long but a 64bit one (like uint64_t), and remove the cast to long in the last two lines.

Comment: "where do I find c.h?"  I fixed the headers so that it will compile on Windows as written.  c.h wasn't necessary and another header mentioned doesn't exist on Windows, while a necessary header was left out.  It's all good now though.

Comment: why do i get a negative

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
unsigned long start = GetTickCount();
// stuff that needs to be timed
unsigned long delta = GetTickCount() - start;
```

`GetTickCount()` is not very precise, but will probably work well. If you see a lot of 0, 16 or 31 millisecond intervals, try timing over longer intervals or use a more precise function like `timeGetTime`.

What I usually do is this:

```
unsigned long deltastack;
int samples = 0;
float average;

unsigned long start = GetTickCount();
// stuff that needs to be timed
unsigned long delta = GetTickCount() - start;

deltastack += delta;
if (samples++ == 10)
{
   // total time divided by amount of samples
   average = (float)deltastack / 10.f;
   deltastack = 0;
   samples = 0;  
}
```

Comment: GetTicksCount rollover every ~45.7 days.

Comment: @Shay: When have you seen Windows up for over 45 days straight? OK, yes that was uncalled for...

Comment: [GetTickCount function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started, up to 49.7 days.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would use the platform independent [std::clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/)

Comment: This function does not return an absolute time reference.

Comment: @chmike he didn't say he needs an absolute time reference

Answer (score 1):

You can check out QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency. These are *very* high resolution- down to one tick per ten cycles on some hardware- timers.