# Equivalent of gettimeofday() for Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi

Does anyone know an equivalent function of the `gettimeofday()` function in Windows environment? I am comparing a code execution time in Linux vs Windows. I am using MS Visual Studio 2010 and it keeps saying, identifier "gettimeofday" is undefined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I use to replace gettimeofday() on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676036/what-should-i-use-to-replace-gettimeofday-on-windows)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`GetLocalTime()` for the time in the system timezone, `GetSystemTime()` for UTC. Those return the date/time in a `SYSTEMTIME` structure, where it's parsed into year, month, etc. If you want a seconds-since-epoch time, use `SystemTimeToFileTime()` or `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`. The `FILETIME` is a 64-bit value with the number of 100ns intervals since Jan 1, 1601 UTC.

For interval taking, use `GetTickCount()`. It returns milliseconds since startup.

For taking intervals with the best possible resolution (limited by hardware only), use `QueryPerformanceCounter()`.

Answer (score 88):

Here is a free implementation:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdint.h> // portable: uint64_t   MSVC: __int64 

// MSVC defines this in winsock2.h!?
typedef struct timeval {
    long tv_sec;
    long tv_usec;
} timeval;

int gettimeofday(struct timeval * tp, struct timezone * tzp)
{
    // Note: some broken versions only have 8 trailing zero's, the correct epoch has 9 trailing zero's
    // This magic number is the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)
    // until 00:00:00 January 1, 1970 
    static const uint64_t EPOCH = ((uint64_t) 116444736000000000ULL);

    SYSTEMTIME  system_time;
    FILETIME    file_time;
    uint64_t    time;

    GetSystemTime( &system_time );
    SystemTimeToFileTime( &system_time, &file_time );
    time =  ((uint64_t)file_time.dwLowDateTime )      ;
    time += ((uint64_t)file_time.dwHighDateTime) << 32;

    tp->tv_sec  = (long) ((time - EPOCH) / 10000000L);
    tp->tv_usec = (long) (system_time.wMilliseconds * 1000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very good. I have a code which was included this implementation. Exactely the same one, but I need to have this code working on Linux and I don't know how to do that. How I would implement this piece of code to compile in Linux using this same implementation using C++ or C? Thks

Comment: @S4nD3r #ifdef _WIN32 ...includes lines above ... #else  #include <sys/time.h>
#endif ... See my usage on my Buddhabrot project: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Michaelangel007/buddhabrot/master/buddhabrot.cpp

Comment: I know this is old, why is tzp passed in, as it isn't referenced?

Comment: @SPlatten In order to be binary compatible with sys/time.h:
int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);
int settimeofday(const struct timeval *tv, const struct timezone *tz);

Comment: @SPlatten tz never should be anything but null... only case it is used, it happens in linux kernel and is earmarked as deprecated.

Answer (score 10):

This is the version of c++11 that uses [chrono](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/).

Thank you, [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant) for advice.

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <chrono>

int gettimeofday(struct timeval* tp, struct timezone* tzp) {
  namespace sc = std::chrono;
  sc::system_clock::duration d = sc::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
  sc::seconds s = sc::duration_cast<sc::seconds>(d);
  tp->tv_sec = s.count();
  tp->tv_usec = sc::duration_cast<sc::microseconds>(d - s).count();

  return 0;
}

#endif // _WIN32
```

Comment: Please don't simply post code, explain what it does and how it solves OPs problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32763779/576911 for a better way to convert `chrono` types to the C timing API types.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want a Windows gettimeofday() implementation, [here is one from PostgreSQL](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/port/gettimeofday.c;h=75a91993b74414c0a1c13a2a09ce739cb8aa8a08;hb=HEAD) that uses Windows APIs and the proper conversions.

However if you want to time code, I suggest you look into [QueryPerformanceCounter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or by [directly invoking the TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter#C.2B.2B) if you're only going to run on x86 for example.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadys I would use the following for gettimeofday() on Windows, which is using GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime() if compiled for Windows 8 or higher and GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() otherwise:

```
#include <Windows.h>
struct timezone {
    int tz_minuteswest;
    int tz_dsttime;
};

int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz)
{
    if (tv) {
        FILETIME               filetime; /* 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 00:00 UTC */
        ULARGE_INTEGER         x;
        ULONGLONG              usec;
        static const ULONGLONG epoch_offset_us = 11644473600000000ULL; /* microseconds betweeen Jan 1,1601 and Jan 1,1970 */

#if _WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8
        GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(&filetime);
#else
        GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&filetime);
#endif
        x.LowPart =  filetime.dwLowDateTime;
        x.HighPart = filetime.dwHighDateTime;
        usec = x.QuadPart / 10  -  epoch_offset_us;
        tv->tv_sec  = (time_t)(usec / 1000000ULL);
        tv->tv_usec = (long)(usec % 1000000ULL);
    }
    if (tz) {
        TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION timezone;
        GetTimeZoneInformation(&timezone);
        tz->tz_minuteswest = timezone.Bias;
        tz->tz_dsttime = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Visual Studio 2015, [`timespec_get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec_get) is available:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static uint64_t
time_ns(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;

    if (timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC) != TIME_UTC)
    {
        fputs("timespec_get failed!", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1000000000 * ts.tv_sec + ts.tv_nsec;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", time_ns());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile using `cl t.c` and run:

```
C:\> perl -E "system 't' for 1 .. 10"
1626610781959535900
1626610781973206600
1626610781986049300
1626610781999977000
1626610782014814800
1626610782028317500
1626610782040880700
1626610782054217800
1626610782068346700
1626610782081375500
```