# how to time the program running time thread included

Tags: c, c++11, pthreads

The problem is clock() function is not allowed, but I have no idea how to deal with time() function in thread.

Comment: probabl;y you can try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds-using-c

Comment: Why are you using `pthread` and not `std::thread` since you marked the post as C++11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use gettimeofday() function to get the start time and end time. While this function work only in Linux. Please refer to [1]:http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday

For this function in windows, please refer to [2]:[Equivalent of gettimeday() for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905892/equivalent-of-gettimeday-for-windows)

Comment: `gettimeofday` should be available on every POSIX system, not only on Linux

Answer (score 1):

Since you marked the post C++11, take a look at the [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library:

```
#include <chrono>

std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
... // <-- Code that you want to time
end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::cout << "Time : " << std::chrono::duration<double>(end - start).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a Linux system, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) then use [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), probably with `CLOCK_REALTIME` & `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID`; see also [pthread_getcpuclockid(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getcpuclockid.3.html) & [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html)

BTW, your `MAX_THREADS` is too big. You should have at most a dozen or two of threads ....