# Struct timeval in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Trying to compile c++ code that was used in Linux with Visual c++. Got error on line:

```
struct timeval ts;
```

Can't find `timeval` structure in Windows. Why?

Comment: i saw this , is it included in winsock.h https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/ns-winsock-timeval

Comment: It's a POSIX (Unix, Linux, macOS) structure. What is the code doing? Perhaps you need to port (rewrite) it for Windows? Or find an existing Windows-port (or another Windows-specific program)?

Comment: [there's no `timeval` in C or C++](https://duckduckgo.com/?sites=cppreference.com&q=timeval&ia=web) so obviously it's some platform-specific thing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905892/equivalent-of-gettimeday-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own timeval structure according to following links [Winsock timeval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/ns-winsock-timeval), [Struct timeval in C](http://www.ccplusplus.com/2011/09/struct-timeval-in-c.html), and other hits on the network.

MSVC defines this in winsock.h

```
typedef struct timeval {
    long tv_sec;
    long tv_usec;
} timeval;
```

Comment: please use `long long` because msvc treats `long` as a 32-bit integer and makes this subject to the Y2K38 bug