# How to use sys/time.h in windows?

Tags: visual-c++, timer

I am using MSVS 2006 and trying to find time in microseconds in my program. I try to call sys/time.h in the header but this error is compiled.

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/time.h': No such file or directory
Error executing cl.exe.
```

and this is my code,

```
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   struc timeval stop,start;
   gettimeofday(&start,NULL);

   /*my function here*/

   gettimeofday(&stop,NULL);
   printf("took %lu usec\n",stop.tv_usec-start.tv_usec);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no sys\time.h header file in MSVC. Instead, try one of the following links for some help coding this on Windows. [stackoverflow 1676036](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676036/what-should-i-use-to-replace-gettimeofday-on-windows) [stackoverflow 2494356](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494356/how-to-use-gettimeofday-or-something-equivalent-with-visual-studio-c-2008)

Comment: mazaya-jamil, can you please share which solution worked for you?

Comment: There is sys\timeb.h

Comment: <sys/time.h> is a POSIX header, not part of the C/C++ standard library.
If you are using C++ the standard header is <ctime>

Comment: Please try using #include  <time.h> instead.