# Visual Studio missing header file "sys/time.h"

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, header-files

I am trying to run a C program in Visual Studio 2013.

In this code I'm using *sys/time.h* header, and I am receiving following errors:

```
error : cannot open source file "sys/time.h"
1>    #include<sys/time.h>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [Cross Platform Development](https://www.google.com/search?q=cross-platform+compilation&oq=cross-platform+compilation&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3383j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=cross-platform+programming+%2B+c%7Cc%2B%2B).

Comment: No because that answer did not help me.

Comment: @ataulanser You're trying to use POSIX headers on Windows. Use the Windows API or C library.

Comment: @Ataulnasar sys/time.h doesn't exist on windows. You'll have to tell us what you need in sys/time.h, and perhaps people can suggest alternatives.

Comment: I am using this to calculate the time complexity of my program in microseconds.

Comment: Time complexity is described in big-O notation, not in microseconds. It cannot be measured, as it's a theoretical concept.

Comment: Sorry about my bad explanation. I want to calculate execution time of a code snippet in microseconds.

Comment: @Ataulnasar: You probably want `QueryPerformanceCounter`, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2150334/586873) answer.

Comment: Thanks all of them for helping me to solve my issue.

Comment: You can find answer in follow link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615571/how-to-use-sys-time-h-in-window)